# Doubts about asymptotic analysis

Tags: limits, asymptotics

I am studying Real Analysis and I came across the following proposition

> $
> \forall \alpha,\beta > 0, a > 1 \\
> \lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty}\frac{(\log_ax)^\alpha}{x^\beta} = 0
> $

This holds when verifying the following limit with Wolfram Alpha ($\alpha = 8, \beta=\frac{1}{2}$): [numeric example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xc69S.png)

However when plotting the same function it looks like
[it is going to infinity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4daKS.png) and not `0`

Why does the plot seem to contradict the computed limit?

Comment: I assume you're asking for help clearing up this seeming contradiction?

Comment: @C-RAM yes I am, I'll edit the question to make it more clear

Comment: You haven't extended the plot far enough, just keep taking $x$ to be larger.

Comment: plot log^8(x)/sqrt(x) (x from 10^6 to 2*10^7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Qiaochu Yuan said, you'd need to keep taking $x$ larger.

But it is surprising indeed cause you'd need to take $x$ to be very large. So let's look at it analytically instead.

The function in your example is given by $f(x) = \dfrac{\ln^8(x)}{\sqrt{x}}$. Let's look at its derivative to see how it behaves.

After a very tedious computation (or wolfram alpha), you observe that

$f'(x) = -\dfrac{(\ln(x) - 16)\ln^7(x)}{2x^{3/2}}$

Now, if you study the signs:

- for $0 < x \leq 1$ : $f'(x) \leq 0$
- for $x \geq 1$ such that $\ln(x) < 16$ : $f'(x) > 0$
- and for $x$ such that $\ln(x) > 16$, $f'(x) < 0$

Now, $\ln(x) = 16 \iff x = e^{16}$. This is a **quite large** number $(\approx 10^6$, so no wonder this behaviour doesn't show up on the graph). So for a very long time, your function is gonna look like it's drifting off to infinity. But then, miraculously, at $x = e^{16}$, it's gonna turn back down, and converge to $0$ (which you can prove rigorously using various methods).

Comment: $f^2$ is easier to derivate.

Comment: Not going to lie, I count anything that's not a polynomial as "too tedious to do by hand" :v

Comment: I find typing $\left(\frac{\ln^8x}{\sqrt x}\right)'$ on WolframAlpha and copy-pasting the result more "tedious" than writing directly $\left(\frac{\ln^{16}x}x\right)'=\frac{16\ln^{15}x}{x^2}-\frac{\ln^{16}x}{x^2},$ which keeps my neuron moving ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much, this seemed counterintuitive at first, but it is very clear now!